# Weird earphones' wiring

Tags: wiring, headphones

So, I'd got a pair of cheap earphones that broken after a while (**Left ear is no more receiving sound**). I defined the problem: it's some broken wires after the button. The thing is that I cannot figure out what goes where.

As you can see in the picture, there are red, blue, two copper (my first guess is that they're ground) wires. ***Short notice***: the whole picture is of the wire that goes to the left ear.

I have connected blue with blue. When I touch the microphone with one of the copper wires, my smartphone switches to the **previous song** (or lets music go to the left ear as well). I have tried connecting the three copper wires (one from one end, two from another) together. Music seems to be playing fine. So, my questions to those who already did it at some point: which wires to connect and where to do it right?
[image: Picture of wiring]

Comment: When taking this type of thing apart, I am **very** careful as to how I open it so I can match the breaks together before the positioning or shape of the breaks are lost... As it becomes **so** hard to re-engineer...

Comment: @SolarMike well, I tried, but the wires were already sort of disconnected, so it didn't really help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in what you purchased in the first place...

[image]

As you may have noticed already the wires in these things are next to impossible to solder. Best bet is to get another one.

Comment: well, I soldered three ground (I suppose  they're ground) wires and they work. Nothing's really impossible.